# How to do bubblesort with strings in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, bubble-sort

I am new to C++ and I have to make the strings appear in ascending order using bubblesort. I have a data file with various strings in it. I stored those values into an array. When I tried the bubblesort code from my text book, the words got sorted like this.

How can I implement this correctly? It's probably something simple that I am missing. Thanks.

[image]

I am not sure why this happened, but here is the code I am using for the bubblesort.

```
void sortListWords(string list[], int count) {
  int temp;
  for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < count - (i + 1); j++)
      if (list[j] > list[j + 1]) {
        temp = list[j];
        list[j] = list[j + 1];
        list[j + 1] = temp;
      }
   }

int main(){
  // call sorting function
  // words are loaded from data file
  sortListWords(wordListing, size);

  // print array to screen
  for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    cout << wordListing[i];

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you want them sorted in lexicographic order? Also please clarify where you are defining `size`.

Comment: I don't see how this would compile, as you're using an `int` temporary variable to swap `std::string` values.

Comment: It is practically the same code as a bubble sort of integers.  Can you write the code to bubble sort an array of integers?  If so, the only difference would be the type that's used -- everything else stays the same.

Comment: @JackRyan Yes. The size is a const called size and its equal to 20.

Comment: @FredLarson I just noticed that. The example from my book was working with integers in an array, so yes it wouldnt compile unless it was a string.

Comment: @LadyT *The example from my book was working with integers in an array,* -- So all you had to do was cut and paste `int` with `std::string`.  Seriously...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thats true. Thats what I thought, I changed the type to string and it printed the duplicated letters. I did keep everything the same.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie No. I changed it from int to string and still got the same error

Comment: @LadyT *// words are loaded from data file* -- You shouldn't read the words from a file at first.  Use hardcoded data to ensure the sort works before you delve into reading from a file.  Right now, we don't know if your test data is correct.

Comment: @LadyT Also, your output statement will just print the entire data on one line, not separate lines.  You need `cout << wordListing[i] << "\n";`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I did catch that. I added a break at the end. Thanks

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I did do some testing and I noticed when adding words that it basically scrambles the words and adds extra characters.

Comment: @LadyT [cannot duplicate](http://ideone.com/jTbWDi).  Took your code (with the `temp` correction), added test data, and outputted the results.

Comment: @LadyT  _// words are loaded from data file --_ Did you verify that reading the wordlist from the file works correctly. Print the wordlist **before** sorting to verify.

Comment: @cwschmidt I checked and verified that the wordlist prints. It lists everything out.

Comment: @LadyT Ok, that's fine. Maybe you can compare your code, with the code of my answer below, to see any differences.

Comment: @cwschmidt Ok. So I did the comparison and I noticed that the sorted words do not print to screen. The regular list prints fine.

Comment: @LadyT You mean, in your code it's not printing, after the sort? Because I tested mine and there it's working. There must be any difference in your solution compared to mine, then.

Comment: @LadyT Remove the call to read the words from the list and instead use the data that I have at the link in the comment, or use the data that is in the answer given by cwshmidt.  Now, run that program -- does it give a sorted list?  If it does, then this whole thing boils down to the data you're reading from the file and a) what exactly is that data and b) whether you read the data correctly.  There is no other conclusion that can be made except that.

Comment: @LadyT You can live test my example here http://ideone.com/IpX5u9

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Just recognized that you did the same as me when I searched for the link you mentioned, ooops ...

Comment: @cwschmidt Ok. So I got it to work with your code. Now I am testing it with the data file strings.

Comment: @LadyT Can you mark my answer as accepted solution, if it works for you and feel satisfied with it? What was the difference to your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just made minimal changes to your example. Please compare it with what you have and you should see, where your problem is:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void sortListWords(std::string list[], int count) {
  std::string temp;
  for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < count - (i + 1); j++) {
      if (list[j] > list[j + 1]) {
        temp = list[j];
        list[j] = list[j + 1];
        list[j + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
}

int main(){
  const int size = 4; 
  std::string wordListing[] = {"Hello", "World", "Fred", "John" };    

  // call sorting function
  // words are loaded from data file
  sortListWords(wordListing, size);

  // print array to screen
  for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    std::cout << wordListing[i] << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

What I did in particular, was exchanging the type of `temp` from `int` to `std::string`. I also added curly brackets around the bodies of your `for` loops to improve readability.

Finally I added the first two lines to your `main` function (for testing):

```
  const int size = 4; 
  std::string wordListing[] = {"Hello", "World", "Fred", "John" };
```

The output is:

```
Fred
Hello
John
World
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this `int temp;` to `string temp;`

Comment: You really should be using std::string

Comment: I assumed the asker is using the std namespace. Thank you